# CloudFlare; getting rid of the direct-connect subdomain

Tags: email, subdomain, mx-record, cloudflare

I'm right now trying to get rid of the **direct-connect** subdomain which gets added automatically and is not visible in the CloudFlare DNS panel. 
I've read about it here; 
https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/22031661-why-do-i-have-a-direct-connect-subdomain 
and there is a very important thing which is bothering me. 
"If you're not receiving mail on the domain, simply delete the MX record;" 
Does that mean that if I only **send** mail from the domain but **not receive** them that I can delete the MX record?

I couldn't care less about receiving mail, but sending is essential for my website.

Thanks,
Martin

For your info; I'm talking about the direct-connect subdomain, not to be confused with the direct subdomain CloudFlare optionally adds. (I have disabled that already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely about receiving mail.

But keep in mind that you might experience difficulties with mail delivery when sent mails pass certain spam filters and the reverse dns entry of your host does not map back to the A record of your domain. (Just as an additional reminder, not that much related to your question.)

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the reminder about the spam filter!